# Where do I have to travel to to see this house?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this

I just saw this picture of a really cool house. Now I would like to now where I have to travel to in order to see this house:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a [hotel in Zaandam, Netherlands](http://www.inntelhotelsamsterdamzaandam.nl/), not far from Amsterdam.

I found this out by using [Google's "search by image" feature.](http://support.google.com/images/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=searchbyimagetooltip&answer=1325808)

Comment: Oh no Amsterdam..... :(

Comment: It uses architectural style from [Zaandam](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=zaandam), as can still be seen (and visited) in [Zaanse Schans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaanse_Schans)

Comment: Technically, it's in Zaandam, not Amsterdam.